# Window Redirect Not Redirecting

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile

I had an earlier question that was related to this problem, although that is fixed a new error has appeared. I have some code that checks if the user is visiting my site via a mobile device. If they do, then I do a simple redirect. However, when the code executes I am not redirected. I know the code runs but no redirect occurs. Instead, some of my javascript code breaks, though no errors appear on my console. You would think Moore's law would have mercy on me.

What's wrong and how could I fix this?

```
// device.mobile() give me true on false on whether device is mobile
if (device.mobile()) {
   window.location.href = "https://itunes.apple.com";
}
```

Comment: there's something you're not telling us or showing us. You're saying device.mobile() returns true then there's absolutely NO way your code wont work. Post the whole script. See: http://js.do/code/53975

Comment: There is a separate library called device.js. I've checked this in console and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try just location.href
window.location.href can be buggy on some mobile devices (ios).

Comment: `location.href` does not work either. The same result is produced.